# Set random location programmatically

Tags: android, location

I am try to using an app which have no service in our region. So my question is it possible to set a particular location to a device location instead of my current location programmatically ?.

Answer (score 0):

Make a collection of latitude and longitude of some available location.then pic them in random order

Answer (score 0):

If its only for testing purposes i would enable "Fake GPS" in the android developer options and use a fake gps app.